# Console Warning with advice to use Props Error

Tags: react-native

> Each Child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

check render method of `HomeScreen`

Component `Stack(<FeaturedRow/>)`
here is the featured Row code :

```js
<FeaturedRow
  key={category.id}
  id={category.id}
  title={category.name}
  description={category.short_description}
/>;
```

What can I do to Avoid this error, on my HomeScreen?
I counterchecked my Sanity backend, updated all schemas, the sanity client is running perfectly.
Nor sure if error is in FeaturedRow component/HomeScreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are trying to map through a list creating multiple `FeaturedRow` I can see that for every one you have a `key` and it is equal to `category.id` but this can happen if you have duplicate ids or some  `null` categories or ids or categories without the property `id`, otherwise you can use the index of the map function :

```js
list.map((category,index)=> 
<FeaturedRow 
 key={index}
//...
/>)
```

But verify your list, try to `console.log(list)` before mapping and see what is the problem